# Is there a way to find out how many memory cells on a SSD are broken

Tags: ssd, cmos

A Solid-state drive consists of Flash-EEPROM (electrically erasable programmable read only memory) which is is build up of FGMOS (Floating-Gate metal–oxide–semiconductor field-effect transistor). With the MLC (multi-level-cells) technology a cell can be changed [5000 to 10000](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7590/) until the isolation of the floating gate is destroyed. If a cell is ruined there are about 10% extra cells which will will be selected by the SSD-control unit to replace the broken cells.

So is there a way to find out how many cells have been replaced (are broken) and how many cells for replacing broken cells are left? (Windows/Linux)